# Lepton PureThermal Not Working in Python3 OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, camera

**Error**
[ERROR:0] open VIDEOIO(AVFOUNDATION): raised unknown c++ exception!

**Specs Detail**

- Macbook Pro 2020 13"
- MacOS Version : Bigsur 11.3.1
- OpenCV Version : 4.5.1
- Python Version : 3.9.4
- Camera : [Lepton 2.5](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=Lepton%202.5&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) connected to [PureThermal 2](https://groupgets.com/manufacturers/getlab/products/purethermal-2-flir-lepton-smart-i-o-module)
- Running on iTerm 2 Build 3.4.6

**Problems Explanation**

- Error while running the python program below [Program Source](https://lepton.flir.com/application-notes/people-finding-with-a-lepton/)
- cameraID = 0 refers to Lepton while cameraID = 1 refers to default webcam.
- If I change the cameraID to 1, the code running perfectly and showing my webcam camera
- I have checked that nothing's wrong with the camera. I tried to open the camera as a webcam from zoom apps, and it's showed.

**CODE**

```
import cv2
cv2.namedWindow("preview")
cameraID = 0
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(cameraID)

if vc.isOpened(): # try to get the first frame
    rval, frame = vc.read()
else:
    rval = False

while rval:
    cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
    rval, frame = vc.read()
    key = cv2.waitKey(20)
    if key == 27: # exit on ESC
        break
```

**OTHER ATTACHMENTS**

1. ERROR SCREENSHOT - TERMINAL:

[image: ERROR SCREENSHOT - TERMINAL]

2. ZOOM - SELECT WEBCAM (Proof Camera Works):

[image: ZOOM - SELECT WEBCAM (Proof Camera Works)]

Comment: post the error as text, not as a screenshot. and mention the error *first*, not as "other attachments". you want this question to be found when someone searches for the error, right?

Comment: your best way forward is to actually debug the code. the *whole* error gave you the source line. it would be wise to also include that as text in your post (also because the piece you did include as text is nearly meaningless without the location it was raised from). here's where that came from: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/a604d44d06841565f03da03d8df3124fca639ca3/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp#L291 it appears that OpenCV's AVFoundation backend hasn't implemented *something* that your camera requires to be implemented. weird pixel format maybe. who knows. file a bug with OpenCV?

Comment: Thank you, but strangely those code works on Ubuntu. Running on parallel desktop (emulator)

Comment: the error comes from AVFoundation, which is an Apple API. I am not surprised that it would run under linux, because linux has other APIs for this.

Comment: The reasons make sense. That's why from the start I really believed that there was nothing wrong with the code above. I suspect the error is in how the image is represented by the device. Given the picture that comes out (maybe) not in RGB format.

I am not really an expert in software development, but I have a new job related to this which is confusing me.

I have also tried step-by-step from this website https://lepton.flir.com/getting-started/ and chose MacOS and followed the instructions. But still no result.

Comment: file a bug with OpenCV. give all details required to reproduce the issue. you should also mention in the bug report that you're willing to test fixes/patches (that implies that you'd be willing to build OpenCV). this approach will increase chances that someone will look at the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(cameraID, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```